# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null ,input type="img"

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Please help me find the error,the normal button "Redial" works fine but the "hangoff" one doesn't..

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="Redial">Call</button>
    <input type="image" src="hangup.png" alt="hangoff">
</div>
```

```js
var hangoff = document.querySelector("#hangoff");
var Redial = document.querySelector("#Redial");

hangoff.onclick = Dropcall;
Redial.onclick = Callagain;

function Dropcall() {
    phone.hangup();
    remoteStream.parentNode.removeChild(remoteStream);
}

function Callagain() {
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting for an id that doesn't exist.

```
div id="buttons">
    <button type="button" id="Redial">Call</button>
    <input type="image" src="hangup.png" alt="hangoff"> <-- does not have id hangoff.
</div>

var hangoff = document.querySelector("#hangoff");
var Redial = document.querySelector("#Redial");
```

Just change your input tag to:

```
<input type="image" src="hangup.png" alt="hangoff" id="hangoff">
```

and that will do the trick. (notice the new "id" attribute)

Comment: @ihoworko i am so thankfull of what you just did,sometimes we play dumb but the answer is just in front of our eyes,thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

`hangoff = document.querySelector("#hangoff")`

this selector is looking for HTMLElement with id **hangoff**

if you want to get element with attribute **alt=hangoff** you have to use next seletor

`hangoff = document.querySelector("[alt='hangoff']")`

or set id for input

`<input type="image" src="hangup.png" id="hangoff">`